# The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row.

Tags: sql

I am using the same script for multiple servers. Its working fine for all the servers but not working for a particular server. Everything is the same for all the servers.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How about explaining what your script does? On which database scheme does it operate? Do all the servers have identical data?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the unique key (`ON` clause) is not unique.

Make sure that there are no possible duplicates for your `ON` clause on that server. It's a data difference between your servers / database environments.

The ON clause must only apply to one possible combination, SQL will not update two records in the `target` with a single value from `source`.

I guess the data is different on your Production server.